# Can't send emails from huawei tablet using outlook address

Tags: email

We have got my son a huawei tablet, and he has an @outlook.com email address. He can receive emails on the tablet, but can't seem to send any-they say they are sending but never arrive, nor do they appear in sent folder or drafts? What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check the SMTP server settings of your mail program. The SMTP server is the one used for sending E-Mails.

The [recommended settings](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040) for the SMTP server for @outlook.com is:

- Server: `smtp-mail.outlook.com`
- SMTP port: `587`
- SMTP encryption method: `STARTTLS`

If it still does not work your network may be blocking port 587. But that would be a problem of the network and not a Android problem.

Comment: Ok thanks-I’ll try that. How would I find out if my network was the problem?

Comment: @user289433 Try different networks like mobile data, home Wifi, Wifi somewhere else. If it works using one network and not using another the networks has obviously an influence.

Comment: Have tried all those, various wifi networks and on mobile data. Still nothing. Any other ideas? Thanks